# How can I install custom git commands (like git hooks) on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, githooks

I am trying to use the [git-hooks](https://github.com/icefox/git-hooks) tool on Windows. But, I cannot figure out how to install the `git-hooks.sh` file such that I can type `git hooks --install` in Git Bash.

I tried putting it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\git`, where a lot of other `git-*.sh` files seem to live. But no luck.

What's the secret?

Answer (score 1):

Like the [git-hooks](https://github.com/icefox/git-hooks/blob/master/README) installation instructions say, you need to "Add git-hooks to your PATH environment variable so 'git hooks' can be run" (or copy `git-hooks` to a directory that already is in your PATH). Neither the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\git` (does that directory really exist for you, I do not see it here) nor the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core` directories are in your PATH by default. Although in fact any directory which is in your PATH would work, I'd recommend to use the directory where `git.exe` is located, usually `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`. Also be sure to keep the original `git-hooks` file name, do not rename the file to `git-hooks.sh` although it is a shell script.